# How to find legal WFS property name on GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, cql-filter

I am querying a GeoServer using a CQL filter and testing it via browser url.  My filter appears to be correct per documentation:

```
https://myserver/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=poi:airports&maxFeatures=50&cql_filter=WITHIN(shape,POLYGON((-13 31,-13 60,26 63,41 50,34 33,17 33,8 38,-13 31)))
```

The server doesn't give me any CQL parsing errors, but reports the following:

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="GetFeature">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Illegal property name: shape</ows:ExceptionText>
```

I tried `the_geom` as well, and that failed too.

What can I change on the GeoServer to yield a correct `WITHIN` result?

Comment: what if you don't specify geom or shape at all?

Comment: You will naturally ask the schema from the service with `https://myserver/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=poi:airports`

Comment: @user30184 - I'd make that an answer

Comment: Turns out there are problems because this WFS goes through a proxy. I'm working with the data owner to troubleshoot and will update the question when it's sorted out.

Comment: So the proxy server issue was squared away, and after following comment from @user30184 I was able to determine that the geometry token was simply "geometry"